# CFWheels DataSource Not Found

Tags: unix, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfwheels

I had to change my web application on cfwheels-1.1.8 to a UNIX server with ColdFusion-10.
Now cfwheels can't find the specified data source (mysql-5) in `config/settings.cfm`.

The error message is: *Wheels.DataSourceNotFound - The data source could not be reached. Suggested action - Make sure your database is reachable and that your data source settings are correct. You either need to setup a data source with the name **db_source** in the CFML Administrator or tell Wheels to use a different data source in **config/settings.cfm***

It worked fine on ColdFusion-9 and Windows Server 2003. I heard that this may have something to do with case sensitivity. I tried some different cases but that didn't solve the problem.
Does anyone have any ideas or know of a solution?

Comment: Can you update the question with the specific error? Is it not finding the _data source_? Or is it not finding the _database_?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new datasource and trying to connect to the new datasource as a test? If that works there must be an issue with the connection information for the original datasource.

Comment: @osekmedia - I tried! I also tried a completly different test web application. Same error message!

Comment: Check to make sure you are using the proper case in usernames and database names for the data source. UNIX is case sensitive with items like that while Windows is not.

Comment: Can you access any datasources outside of the cfweels framework? I assume there is an issue with your connection string. Do you have the Databases on a different server? If so you may need to add a hole in the firewall to allow the remote connection. If it is on your server, I would check the case of usernames, passwords and your connection string.

Comment: Outside cfwheels everything works fine! The database is on the same server. I had a few problems with case sensitivity on other web applications. I am not sure if I can/should change something in the cfwheels framework?

Comment: see this example: https://docs.ephox.com/display/EditLive/MySQL+in+ColdFusion+Example+Documentation